# Error in select statement - no value given for a parameter

Tags: c#, email, sql

I wanted to send an auto email to the user regarding his/her password after he/she has entered the username. But i ran into an error that states: "**No value given for one or more required parameters.**"

The following is my codes:

```
//string username = Request.Form["UserName"];
string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\mydatabase";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT password, email FROM [users] WHERE username = ?";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["UserName"];
    con.Open();

    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string password = reader["password"].ToString();
            string accountemail = reader["email"].ToString();

            string from = "office email"; //send from admin/mail server
            string to = "accountemail";  //send to respective user
            string subject = "forgot password";
            string body = "This is the password that you have requested: " + password + ". Please do not reply, this is an automated email."; //content of the email
            try
            {
                var fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();
                m.Add(to);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.ReplyToList.Add(fromAddress);
                mail.To.Add(m[0]);
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "mypassword"); 
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

                smtp.Send(mail);

                MessageBox.Show("Success, your password has been sent to you.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug and let us know from which line you are getting this error?

Comment: I think the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is the only place where that error could be raised.

Comment: Yeah I figured @The_Black_Smurf. Cheers!

Comment: @Sam it is the cmd.ExecuteReader :(

Comment: @Ariel Seah, as the mailer isn't involved in the problem, I think you should remove it from your code sample to get a more [consise question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See my answer below. Use the parameter name as @user

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can also take your email sending code out of the while loop.

```
string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\mydatabase";
string password = ""; 
string accountemail="";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT password, email FROM [users] WHERE username = @user";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["UserName"];
                con.Open();

                using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        password = reader["password"].ToString();
                        accountemail = reader["email"].ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
                    string fromaddress = "office email"; //send from admin/mail server
                    string toaddress = accountemail;  //send to respective user
                    string subject = "forgot password";
                    string body = String.Concat("This is the password that you have requested: " ,password, ". Please do not reply, this is an automated email."); //content of the email
                    try
                    {
                        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromaddress);
                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                        MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();
                        m.Add(toaddress);
                        mail.Subject = subject;
                        mail.From = new MailAddress(fromaddress);
                        mail.Body = body;
                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        mail.ReplyToList.Add(fromAddress);
                        mail.To.Add(m[0]);
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "mypassword"); 
                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

                        smtp.Send(mail);

                        MessageBox.Show("Success, your password has been sent to you.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex.Message);
                        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);
                    }
```

Comment: Hey the error is coming from the OleDbDataReader with the same error message.

Comment: @ArielSeah put `var test = Request.Form["UserName"];` on the top of the code and put a breakpoint on it. See if it's returning a value you expect.

Comment: Yup i did what you said, it will return a value but however the  OleDbDataReader still have the same error as No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: try this `Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Request.Form["UserName"]);`

Comment: no luck :/ in addition, with the following error as well: "System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Answer (score 0):

OleDB is a bit picky with parameters:  It supports positional parameters but not the named parameters.  I don't have the setup to test your code but you could try to set the parameters value without specifying the parameter name.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(Request.Form["UserName"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your command parameter

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT password, email FROM [users] WHERE username = @user";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["UserName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\mydatabase";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [password], [email] FROM [users] WHERE username = ?";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["UserName"];
    con.Open();

using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string password = reader["password"].ToString();
        string accountemail = reader["email"].ToString();

        string from = "office email"; //send from admin/mail server
        string to = "accountemail";  //send to respective user
        string subject = "forgot password";
        string body = "This is the password that you have requested: " + password + ". Please do not reply, this is an automated email."; //content of the email
        try
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();
            m.Add(to);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.ReplyToList.Add(fromAddress);
            mail.To.Add(m[0]);
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "mypassword"); 
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

            smtp.Send(mail);

            MessageBox.Show("Success, your password has been sent to you.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
    }
    }
}
}
```

use braces in the string only problem will be resolved